# Find whether a Windows service has been started at startup or manually

Tags: c, windows, service

I have a bunch of Windows services that I created, with start type automatic. I would like to start them with different delays after the OS startup. However, when started manually I would like to start them immediately.

The startup type Automatic (delayed start) is not suitable for me as I need different delay for each service.

I was considering adding some kind of sleep in the services source code, applied only when the service is executed at OS startup.

However I haven't been able to find a way to distinguish between a manual and automatic start of the service.

I've checked environment variables, but they are exactly the same in both cases.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:**
Is it possible to find the time when all automatic services have been started? It could gives us a solution. If the service starts before this time, then it is an automatic startup. If not it is a manual one.

Comment: Why do you need delays between the services starting?

Comment: It's to prevent overloading the server if all services start at the same time (or in a close time interval).

Comment: Can't the server look after itself? *Overload* is hardly a denial of service attack here. Adding seconds delay will only make the boot time even slower.

Comment: Well, actually if the server is overloaded, it takes more time for the services to initialize. I won't go into details, but the services relies on other process/servers. And when the services take too much time to initialize, some timeouts are busted, causing errors. I know that the solution would be to fix the other processes, but I can't do that :(.

Comment: [CreateService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450.aspx): *"lpBinaryPathName: [...] The path can also include arguments for an auto-start service. For example, "d:\\myshare\\myservice.exe arg1 arg2". These arguments are passed to the service entry point (typically the main function)."* Not entirely perfect, since the user could pass the same arguments when starting the service manually.

Comment: Don't start the services automatically.  Have a single very simple service (started automatically) whose only job is to start the other services in sequence at the appropriate times.

Comment: The arguments given in lpBinaryPathName are actually always provided to the service whether it started manually or automatically.

They are given to the application entry point (main function). Some additional parameters can be specified when starting the service manually (using sc or Services > Properties > start). But in that case they are given to the service entry point (service main).